# How to revise java?

Tags: java

Ok so this isn't 100% programming question, for which I'm really sorry, but still this is the best place I know to ask it.

In ~2weeks time I'll have a job interview, first they'll make me take a test from Java and I was wondering what's the best way to prepare for it? I bet it will be something similar to SCJP (but probably much easier), are there any (short) books, tutorials that are worth reading? I did order the SCJP book by Sierra/Bates but I won't be able to read it before the test.

Don't get me wrong I do have experience with Java etc. but I really want to get the job so I want to go there well prepared.

Also marry Xmas to everyone, no matter what religion you are.

Comment: It's actually 100% programming related, and not at all off topic. Similar questions however have been already asked and answered several times; maybe you should take a look to see if there's something you like! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+books

Comment: For all of us non-British folk, "revise" apparently also means "to review in preparation for an examination": http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revise

Comment: I am already married and I doubt if one would marry xmas. Merry Xmas! :)

Comment: There is no way they would make you take the SCJP at an interview.  That's a ~2 hour test.  Go buy HeadFirst Java

Comment: Thanks, but what has xmas got to do with religion anyway? ;)

Comment: Around here X-MAS is a beer :)  http://www.royalunibrew.com/default.aspx?id=169&pagenum=8

Answer (score 9):

> *Don't get me wrong I do have
>   experience with Java etc. but I really
>   want to get the job so I want to go
>   there well prepared.*

**If you have enough experience don't worry about the test.** Don't try to impress your next boss with an awesome test that does not reflect your current knowledge. Read Joel's posts about interviewing:

> The second worst kind of interviewer
>   is the Quiz Show Interviewer. This is
>   the kind of person who thinks that
>   smart means “knows a lot of facts.”
>   They just ask a bunch of trivia
>   questions about programming and give
>   points for correct answers. Just for
>   fun, here is the worst interview
>   question on Earth: “What’s the
>   difference between varchar and
>   varchar2 in Oracle 8i?” This is a
>   terrible question. There is no
>   possible, imaginable correlation
>   between people that know that
>   particular piece of trivia and people
>   that you want to hire. Who cares what
>   the difference is? You can find out
>   online in about fifteen seconds!
>   Remember, smart does not mean “knows
>   the answer to trivia questions.”
>   Anyway, software teams want to hire
>   people with aptitude, not a particular
>   skill set. Any skill set that people
>   can bring to the job will be
>   technologically obsolete in a couple
>   of years, anyway, so it’s better to
>   hire people that are going to be able
>   to learn any new technology rather
>   than people who happen to know how to
>   make JDBC talk to a MySQL database
>   right this minute.
>
> *quoted from ["The Guerrilla Guide to Interviewing (version 3.0)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/GuerrillaInterviewing3.html) by Joel Spolsky*

If you need to impress someone to get the job, may be that's not a good place to work...

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you pick up *Effective Java, 2nd Edition* by Joshua Bloch and read it **cover to cover**. It details several **"best practices"** for Java and will have you walking into the interview knowing for example things like:

- when to use **Static Factory Methods**
- when to use the **Builder Pattern**
- what a **Singleton** is and how to enforce it
- how to **prevent instantiation** of a class
- why to **avoid finalizers**
- the general contract for overriding **equals and hashcode**
- to **use accessor methods** instead of public fields
- to **prefer lists to arrays**
- to **favor generic types**
- to **use enums** instead of int constants
- to **return empty collections** or arrays instead of null
- to **prefer for-each loops** over traditional for loops
- to **avoid float and double** if exact values are needed
- beware of performance loss when doing **string concatenation**
- refer to objects by their **interfaces**

Not to mention the **other 40 or so topics** that I can't remember off the top of my head. If you're able to talk about these topics and **demonstrate an understanding**, then there's no reason you shouldn't be in the running for the position since learning this material will already put you in the **top 10 percentile of Java developers**.

Answer (score 2):

I have a little book with "Exam Cram" in its title. The emphasis is on "little;" you can read through it in a single evening. It describes in prose all the important features of Java, it contains tables of quick facts that will be essential, and it covers, briefly, all of the SCJP exam.

For the less than eidetic, it gives hints on how to write yourself a crib sheet from memory once the test starts (meaning you can carry a bit of what you need to know in short-term memory). There are also some tips on pitfalls and such. Finally, and perhaps most importantly, there is at least one practice exam in it (haven't looked at it in a while) and a bunch of drill questions.

Alas, from what I see at Amazon, the book I recommended only covers Java 2: [http://www.amazon.com/Java-Exam-Cram-310-025/dp/1576102912](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1576102912) Still, there are bound to be similar, more timely books.

This one: [http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1261601183&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060) by Kathy Sierra is similar and about Java 6.

---

Some people would (and in fact did) recommend buying a general purpose Java book. Ideally, all you should have to do is learn "all of Java" and then you'd be ready for the exam. But this is not a winning strategy!

#### related anecdote

The first time I took my driver's test with the DMV, I had a long wait and quickly skimmed through a little info booklet they provided. I easily scored 100.

I later had to take the test again. Knowing the test was laughably easy, I spurned the booklet and failed the theoretical test. The booklet didn't contain anything I didn't already know: But being by the same people who administer the test, it contained the same wording, it had similar situations from the test, it emphasized similar topics and situations. In a few minutes, it could easily make the difference between passing and failing.

#### Conclusion

Same approach with these "prepare for test XXX" books. It's a racket, but the special-purpose prep books work better at preparing you for the test than general knowledge (or general knowledge books) do.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should read Eckel's [Thinking in Java](http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4). In this book many specific java features are considered.

Answer (score 0):

Brush up or learn the following :

- Simple concepts e.g. **static** keyword, importance of **equals** and **hashCode**, etc.
- How **generics** in java work?
- How **threading** works, **deadlock**, **race conditions**, etc.
- How java deals with memory. Can **garbage collection** be enforced?
- Basics of **OOP**.
- Basics of **String**, **StringBuffer**, **StringBuilder**, **RuntimeException**, etc.
- Design patterns, e.g. **singleton**, **visitor**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prepare my self to explain what I already know about java and how much I would like to work for that company.

While the programming knowledge is essential, I don't think you can improve much further in two weeks.

Better would be for you to prepare to answer, why do you want to work there, why should they hire you. etc.

Comment: This is indeed a very good advice, but unfortunately from what I know first you need to get a decent score on the tests (as there are obviously other parts aside from Java). Only they will they invite you for an interview.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is HeadFirst Java to brush up on anything you may have some issues on.  The SCJP is something that they may make you take upon hiring within 6 months for example, however I have never heard of a company making someone take a proctored test at an interview.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write something small but useful in Java, in whatever environment they're going to be using (applets, JSP, desktop...). That way you won't freeze trying to remember how to do e.g. console output.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, show them some Java code you've obviously written and that you're proud of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the language well then [The Really Big Index](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) will be invaluable. It's a huge list and you'd struggle to read it straight though but for a reference it's fantastic. Read it along with a set book like Thinking in Java or the SCJP book you've already ordered and you'll be absolutely fine.